# Delete oldest rows for specific ID - Sybase derived table issue

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, sybase

My stored procedure has a temp table which contains a column of ID values.  An ID can appear in the temp table several times.  There is also a Date column in the temp table.  I need to write a query (Sybase database) that will delete all entries that isn't the Max date for each ID.

```
ID    |  Date
12345 |  2015/01/23
98763 |  2015/01/22
12345 |  2015/01/20
98763 |  2015/01/21
```

So in this case the

```
12345 | 2015/01/20 and 98763 | 2015/01/21
```

entries will be deleted.

I've created the following:

```
DELETE #temp
FROM #temp t1
left JOIN 
(
   select ID, MAX(Date) maxdt
   from #temp t2
   group by ID
) t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
  and t1.ID = t2.Date
where t2.ID is null
```

Though it turns out Sybase (or at least the version I'm using) does not allow derived tables within a Delete or Update statememt.  Is there another way this could be rewritten, or a different query approach to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Below code leaves only the newest rows:

```
delete #temp   
from #temp t       
where not exists(select 1
                 from #temp t2 
                 where t.id = t2.id
                 and t2.date < t.date)
```